# Use javascript function with onclick on an input field

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a submit form and want an alarm that pops up after the user send the form.

Heres the part of code that's not working for me

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input onclick="formSuc" type="submit" class="btn btn-box" value="ABSENDEN">
</div>

<script>
  function formSuc(){
    alarm("test");
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parenthesis when calling a function:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input onclick="formSuc()" type="submit" class="btn btn-box" value="ABSENDEN">
</div>

<script>
  function formSuc() {
    alert("test");
  }
</script>
```